# Counting rows for all tables at once

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and would like to know how I can get a list of all tables with the number of records in each.

I know I can get a list of tables using the `sys.tables` view, but I'm unable to find the count.

Thank you

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From here: http://web.archive.org/web/20080701045806/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-sql-server-tables-and-their-row-counts.html

```
SELECT 
    [TableName] = so.name, 
    [RowCount] = MAX(si.rows) 
FROM 
    sysobjects so, 
    sysindexes si 
WHERE 
    so.xtype = 'U' 
    AND 
    si.id = OBJECT_ID(so.name) 
GROUP BY 
    so.name 
ORDER BY 
    2 DESC
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what purpose does `ORDER BY 2 DESC` serve?

Comment: @jdl134679 it orders it my rowCount, with the table with most rows first

Comment: @jleach Yes, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on ORDER BY. "A sort column can be specified as a name or column alias, or a nonnegative integer representing the position of the column in the select list."

Answer (score 22):

For what it's worth, the sysindexes system table is deprecated in SQL 2008.  The above still works, but here's query that works going forward with SQL 2008 system views.

```
select
schema_name(obj.schema_id) + '.' + obj.name,
row_count
from (
    select
        object_id,
        row_count = sum(row_count)
    from sys.dm_db_partition_stats
    where index_id < 2  -- heap or clustered index
    group by object_id
) Q
join sys.tables obj on obj.object_id = Q.object_id
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted (after I put a few WHERE conditions after the join.)

Answer (score 5):

I might add that sysindexes.rows is an approximation of the number of rows. I'd run a [`DBCC UPDATEUSAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188414.aspx) if you need a more accurate value. We had this issue on a DB with tables containing over 47-50 million rows and we thought we'd lost around half a million from each of them.

Comment: `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE` doesn't seem to fix all potential issues here. I tried `update statistics dbo.table_name with rowcount = 100000, pagecount = 100000` the DBCC fixed the false manually set page count but not the false row count (but very much an edge case I imagine!)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT 
    [TableName] = so.name, 
    [RowCount] = MAX(si.rows) 
FROM 
    sysobjects so, 
    sysindexes si 
WHERE 
    so.xtype = 'U' 
    AND 
    si.id = OBJECT_ID(so.name) 
GROUP BY 
    so.name 
ORDER BY 
    2 DESC
```

http://web.archive.org/web/20080701045806/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-sql-server-tables-and-their-row-counts.html

Answer (score 1):

This is my method:

```
create table #rowcount (tablename varchar(128), rowcnt int)
exec sp_MSforeachtable 
   'insert into #rowcount select ''?'', count(*) from ?'
select * from #rowcount
    order by tablename
drop table #rowcount
```

works like a charm

Comment: It seems to be slower than the other options, though it may be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

These all ways will give you the row count in the result set of a select query. SSMS also gives you an option to see the object details via: **"Object Explorer Details" pane**. 
This is available for 2005 and all versions after that

Object Explorer Details is a component of SQL Server Management Studio. It provides a tabular view of all the objects in the server and presents a user interface to manage them.

To reach "Object Details Window":
Click Object you want to see details for in "Object Explorer" pane and **press F7**.
Read More: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191146(v=sql.90).aspx

Pros:

1. **Much faster then the select query as SQL Server stores this information**
2. **Don't need to write/copy-paste the select query everytime - you are just one F7 away**
3. Gives you much more information and not just about row count

Note: You might not have Row Count coming in the Object Details pane by default, you can click on the column header and bring it in.