# Anything faster than count(1) from tableA to find row counts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there any thing from which we can faster get the no. of rows in a table instead of using count(1). Further there are two cases :

a) when we want to get the no. of rows in a table.

b) when we just want to know if there is at-least one row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Makes sure you test that your solutions are actually faster and give the same results: I'm pretty sure that the suggestions to solve [a] by querying the system tables are simply faulty emulations of what `SELECT COUNT(*)` is already doing.

Comment: @egrunin: Easy to see that [the plans are not the same](http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/3977/executionplan.jpg) and that `COUNT(*)`  scans the whole table. I agree some testing would be in order and some research into when exactly the system table metadata gets updated though.

Comment: @Martin Smith: so now I have to wonder, if the built-in `SELECT COUNT()` implementation isn't as fast as these suggestions, *is there a good reason why not?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a)
You can get table row counts from system tables, 1 example is as per Uri Dimant's [blog post here](http://dimantdatabasesolutions.blogspot.com/2008/05/getting-row-count-of-table-in-sql.html).

b)
I'd always use EXISTS:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM YourTable)
```

Answer (score 2):

b) when we just want tot know if there is atleast one row.

`SELECT TOP 1 myField
FROM myTable [WHERE .....]`

Answer (score 2):

To know the count of all rows in the table without scanning them you can use

```
select SUM(row_count) AS row_count
from sys.dm_db_partition_stats
where object_id = object_id('dbo.tblName')
    and index_id < 2
```

I'm not sure if there are any caveats with that approach. (Presumably it might either include the count for non committed records or not include changes made within your current transaction)

Comment: Isn't that what `SELECT COUNT(*)` actually does, and without your caveats?

Comment: @egrunin: No. [Execution Plans...](http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/3977/executionplan.jpg)

Comment: Is it advisable to use this ? further is this what you are using as a pro ?

Answer (score 1):

b) Linq-to-Sql generates

```
EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Table....)
```

Answer (score 1):

a) No.

b) You can use the `exists` function, which only checks if there is a result and doesn't actually get the result.

Answer (score 0):

There is this approach, using sysobjects and sysindexes:

[Counting rows for all tables at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428458/counting-rows-for-all-tables-at-once)

It's worked well for me in the past.