# Tips on designing a PowerBI report showing table counts from two databases

Tags: powerbi

I'm a Power BI beginner and intent to build a report showing tables counts between two databases.
This is to ensure that the each respective tables in two databases are in sync (there is a separate process that "refreshes" the data from source database to target database).

My queries are how should I go about designing such a report:-

1. I think I should use direct query mode ?
2. Should I use custom M code to build some consolidated "query" or just use standard method for each table in each database and then use measures (for calculating counts using DAX functions such as `countrows` ).
3. Does it makes sense to do this calculation (for each table) in database as in stored proc etc and then use this database SP in Power BI?
4. What visualizations should I choose ? I intent to just compare counts of each table in respective database in real time, maybe showing some green indicator (table wise) when the count is same and a red indicator when the count differs. Does Power BI provide such a visualization or I should explore Power BI custom visuals?

BTW the two databases are: Hive and SQL Server (PDW)

Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 2):

1) I would not use DirectQuery, as you would potentially be executing queries on your databases, that could take a while to complete, depending on the number of records in each table, and the response times of the database. The downside of not using DirectQuery is, that you would have to manually hit the "Refresh" button in Power BI Desktop, or schedule a data refresh at regular intervals, if deploying the Power BI report to PowerBI.com.

2+3) If all you need is the count of rows within each table, the most important thing is to make sure that this count is ultimately performed by your databases. It would be a tremendous waste to load all the data into your Power BI model, only to have it return the count of rows using DAX. Instead, use a [SQL query like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4742539/1594867) to let the database count the number of rows in each table, and return the aggregated results to Power BI. If you have the option of putting the SQL query into a stored proc, by all means do so! Use one Power Query for each database, add a column with the name of the database, and then append them all together, so that you end up with a table inside Power BI that looks like this:

```
| Database | Table    | Rows      |
| -------- | -------- | --------- |
| Hive     | Customer |     12345 |
| Hive     | Orders   |    123456 |
| SQL      | Customer |     12356 |
| SQL      | Orders   |    123400 |
```

4) Once you have a table like the one showed above inside Power BI (let's call the table "FactRowCount"), I would simply create a measure using the following DAX:

```
RowDiffs = CALCULATE(SUM('FactRowCount'[Rows]), 'FactRowCount'[Database] = "Hive")
    - CALCULATE(SUM('FactRowCount'[Rows]), 'FactRowCount'[Database] = "SQL")
```

Then, to visualize the data, add the [Table]-column to a matrix visual together with the [RowDiffs] measure and apply dynamic (color) formatting to the measure inside the visual. You could also do percentage differences, etc. depending on your preferences.